# mysqli query returns false but no error message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a very straightforward SELECT query within the context of a PHP class which is returning false (failed) but I am unable to retrieve the associated error information. The odd thing is that the call worked fine until I had to reorganize the mysql database - without revising the PHP code obviously it fails - the result is false - but where is the error message?

Code is as follows:

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $_connection;
    private $_result;
    private $_lastQuery;
    private $_error;

    public function __construct($dbase) {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $dbase);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($this->_connection, 'utf8');
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->_lastQuery = $query;
        $this->_result = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query);
        $this->_error = $this->_connection->error;
        return $this->_result;
    }
}
```

No error string appears in $this->_error; also not revealed when inspected during debugging (PHPStorm).
When executing the query via the command line, the (expected) error messaging is generated.

Comment: Where does $this->_error come from? Its not defined in your Database class.

Comment: TBH, I'm not entirely sure about this, but shouldn't `$this->_error = $this->_connection->error;` be `$this->_error = $this->_connection->_error;`?

Comment: why you're storing query result in a class variable?

Comment: Are you sure that DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS have values inside the class??

Comment: as of your question - why don't you post the code you run? what answer you expect?

Comment: ^--« At least we're not ignorant.

Comment: sorry, I edited out irrelevant code and removed the definition for $this->error

Comment: the query works fine when it is correct - returns the expected result - it 's only when the query is erroneous that a) $this->result is false (expected) but $this->_connection->error is set to an empty string.

Comment: Well, what kind of answer you expect posting this irrelevant excerpt from the real code? Like someone would read it, add absent code, evaluate it mentally, and give you answer? What if this added code will be different from your own?

Comment: I'd be happy to post the entire class, all 80 lines, if you think it would help

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the problem is actually with xdebug.

Comment: the same probem here. but if you set some variable with this error, you somehow can see this error in debugger (in this variable only): $myerr=$mysqli->error;// $mysqli->error is empty while $myerr is not

Comment: and `zend_extension=xdebug.dll` not included in `php.ini`, it is in `phpforApache.ini`